# Need help with accepting decimals as input in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I have written a program in C# that runs the Pythagorean Theorem. I would love some help on allowing the program to accept decimal points from the user input. This is what I have.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Project_2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sideA = 0;
        int sideB = 0;
        double sideC = 0;
        Console.Write("Enter a integer for Side A ");
        sideA = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter a integer for Side B ");
        sideB = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        sideC = Math.Pow((sideA * sideA + sideB * sideB), .5);
        Console.Write("Side C has this length...");
        Console.WriteLine(sideC);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

I have been trying to research this by using the Math.Abs and so on only to receive build errors. Help in the write path would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Decimal.Parse() on the user input

Comment: If I use that then the Math.Pow function stops working because it can't convert a double to a decimal.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using Decimal.TryParse.  This pattern is very safe since it traps the exceptions and returns a boolean to determine the success of the parse operation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx

Comment: A nitpick: Generally speaking, the various `TryParse` patterns don't "trap" exceptions; they avoid them altogether.

Comment: Fair enough, but they do not expose any exception to the user.  That is why this is a good pattern.  I use this pattern in custom code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Math.Pow doesnt take in decimal. There is already another question on SO about Math.Pow and decimal. Use double.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double sideA = 0;
            double sideB = 0; 
            double sideC = 0; 
            Console.Write("Enter an integer for Side A ");
            sideA = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); 
            Console.Write("Enter an integer for Side B ");
            sideB = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); 
            sideC = Math.Pow((sideA * sideA + sideB * sideB), .5); 
            Console.Write("Side C has this length..."); 
            Console.WriteLine(sideC); 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: That was the trick. My error was with the assignments of the sides. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: or try "Enter a decimal for Side B " ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
static decimal RequestDecimal(string message)
{
    decimal result;
    do 
    {
         Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
    while (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result));
    return result;
}
```