# Accepting only decimals and numbers in Console.ReadLine

Tags: c#

I have just made a program to calculate the total cost of an item or items given the quantity and price. One of my concerns is in the Cost of Item field, it does not accept decimals at all. I would also like both fields to not accept letters. I have seen something about `TryParse` but I am unsure of how to use this and how it works. Any help is appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace QuantityPrice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Quantity;
            int Cost;
            Console.WriteLine("How much is the item you are buying? (In Canadian Dollars)");
            Cost = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("How many of the item are you buying? (In Canadian Dollars)");
            Quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var TotalCost = Quantity * Cost * 1.13;
            Console.WriteLine("Your total cost is:");
            Console.WriteLine("$" + TotalCost);
            Console.ReadLine();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i do that? It gives me an error

Comment: @ValidBass Just approve my edit will do.

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry, new here

Comment: @ValidBass Put 4 spaces in front of every new line of your code will appear like above. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use decimals instead of int and to get the value, just ask for it as long as it is not a valid decimal like in this answer [Need help with accepting decimals as input in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286455/need-help-with-accepting-decimals-as-input-in-c-sharp#7286516)
that you could use directly like this:

```
var cost = RequestDecimal("How much is the item you are buying? (In Canadian Dollars)");
```

Use an equivalent function to get an int for quantity

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using `int.Parse` to extract the values from the user input. The `int` type is only for integers. If you want to handle decimals, use either `float` or `double` (for general mathematics where you want a floating decimal point) or `decimal` (for fixed point arithmetic such as currency).

As a general style comment, use "camel case" (starting with a lower case character) for variable names instead of "Pascal case" (starting with an upper case character).