# Reading float variable from user input inside a function

Tags: c#, function, user-input

I am modifying a simple c# program that shows the area of a rectangle whose width and height you write in the console(initially the width and height's values were given in the program).However, the user input part doesn't seem to work.I have tried `Convert.ToInt32()` and I even changed the variables to be integers even though they should be float's, thinking that the conversion will work that way, but to no avail.The error I get is :"error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'.".

The question is, what do I do to make this work?I think I could just remove the function and just write the code in the main one, but I'm trying to learn to use the functions and I would be thankful if you could show me a way of giving the variable's value the keyboard input without removing the function.

'

```
class Rectangle
{
    // member variables
    double length;
    double width;
    public void Acceptdetails()

      {
        //read length and width from the keyboard
        length = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        width = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    public double GetArea()
    {
        return length * width;
    }

    public void Display()
    {   //display the length width and area
        Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
        Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
        Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
    }
}

class ExecuteRectangle
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        r.Acceptdetails();
        r.Display();
        Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

'

Comment: _length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());_

Comment: Have you already corrected the issue in your example?  I couldn't see the problem, so I copied this into a quick project in Visual Studio and sure enough, it works as expected.  Your error message should give you a line number.  What specific line of code is the error from?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using decimal.TryParse()

see this answer for details: [Need help with accepting decimals as input in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286455/need-help-with-accepting-decimals-as-input-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine() is a function you forgot ()

this should work

```
        length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: I edited the question,since I realised that it sounded like I couldn't convert them to integers.What I needed was converting them to float type since they should be able to get decimals.Also sorry about the parantheses, I guess while trying to get them to work I forgot to add them and I didnt check the code when I uploaded it(ups).

Comment: Use decimal decimal.Parse()